# How recognize current route in angular2 injectable

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, angular-routing

I want recognize current route in angular2 service provider for get only actual settings of my spa in dependency of active link.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Inject the following in your component controller:

`private route: ActivatedRoute`

Comment: Well. How it use? I inject that in component, get route.toString() but it return me empty object.